# get value of parent <tr> when clicking <td>

Tags: jquery

I've got the following table structure:

```
<tr class="tabrow" val="12345"> 
    <td class="clickable">abcde</td> 
    <td class="clickable">fghij</td> 
    <td class="clickable">2016-03-03 15:35:45</td> 
</tr>
```

I want a way of getting the `val` of the row when I click on any of the fields. So far I have got this:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
    evID = $(this).closest('tr').val();
    alert(evID);
})
```

This is not working; it just returns a blank result. I also tried this, which also doesn't work:

```
evID = $(this).parent().val();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use `.attr(attributeName)` instead of `.val()`,

```
$('.clickable').on('click',function() {
   evID = $(this).closest('tr').attr("val");
   alert(evID);
});
```

`.val()` can be used over form elements which are having value property in its object(node object).

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/w17fx3sn/)

Comment: `<tr class="tabrow" val="newVal"> 
    <td class="clickable">A</td> 
    <td class="clickable">B</td> 
    <td class="clickable">2016-03-03 15:35:45</td> 
</tr>
<tr class="tabrow" val="12345"> 
    <td class="clickable">abcde</td> 
    <td class="clickable">fghij</td> 
    <td class="clickable">2016-03-03 15:35:45</td> 
</tr>`


What if I want B from upper <tr class="tabrow" val="newVal"> ??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `closest()` to find the parent `tr`, then `attr()` to get the `val` attribute from the it:

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
   var evID = $(this).closest('tr').attr("val");
   console.log(evID);
})
```

Note though that `val` is not a valid attribute on a `tr` element and will mean that your HTML is invalid. This is also the reason why your use of the `val()` method didn't work. Instead you should use a `data-*` attribute and retrieve it via `data()`:

```
<tr class="tabrow" data-val="12345"> 
    <td class="clickable">abcde</td> 
    <td class="clickable">fghij</td> 
    <td class="clickable">2016-03-03 15:35:45</td> 
</tr>
```

```js
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
   var evID = $(this).closest('tr').data("val");
   console.log(evID);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For a table-row element, `val` is not a valid attribute. You should use a data-attribute like `data-val` instead:

```
<tr class="tabrow" data-val="12345"> 
   <td class="clickable">abcde</td>  
   <td class="clickable">fghij</td> 
   <td class="clickable">2016-03-03 15:35:45</td> 
</tr>
```

And then try to get that value when you click on the table cell. Assuming that the clicked `td` is always a childNode of the meant `tr` (which should be).

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function(e) {
   var valueFromParentTR = $(e.currentTarget).parent().attr("data-val");
   console.log(valueFromParentTR); // don't use alert, just open your console.
});
```

You can use any `data-[whatever]` attribute on any element for these kinds of purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Find nearest tr and append a class example:

```
$(this).closest('tr').addClass('blink_me');
```

other replacements for `addClass('blink_me')` etc...

```
css('background-color','#fff')
removeClass('blink_me')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attribute in tr:

```
<tr class="tabrow" data-val="12345"> 
    <td class="clickable">abcde</td> 
    <td class="clickable">fghij</td> 
    <td class="clickable">2016-03-03 15:35:45</td> 
</tr>
$(".clickable").("click", function(){
    var clickedTdParent = $(this).parent();
    var trValue = clickedTdParent.data().val
})
```